# How to refer to elements in a php file that are not mentioned in <form>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a PHP file that is triggered onClick of a button in a linked HTML file. I have a textbox in the same form that triggers the PHP file and I refer it in the PHP file like this

HTML

```
<form action="phpinfo.php" method="POST">
    <input name="shirtText" id="name" class="input-field" type="text" value="Enter text"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

PHP

```
$text=$_POST['shirtText'];
```

However there are some buttons like `select option` drop down bar and other click-able `div`s. How do i mention these `Divs` or other elements in PHP like how we do it Jquery by writing $('#id') or $('.class')?

Comment: what do you wanna do with those elements in php? get their values or something else?

Comment: You have to put everything your server needs in the form somehow.

Comment: @AminJafari i have four DIV's to change the color of an SVG. I want to add the selected color in mySQL database?

Comment: The most common way is to use a hidden input inside your form. You can set the value of it via jQuery. Once it is set, that value will be available when your Form is submitted.

Comment: Add a `print_r($_POST)` to your PHP file and you will see all of the items that were transmitted during the posting of the form.

Comment: the only way that I can think of for your case is to store those values in variables and send them to the server using ajax!

Answer (score 3):

```
<form id="changeColor" action="phpinfo.php" method="POST">
    <input name="shirtText" id="name" class="input-field" type="text" value="Enter text"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Submit"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="svgColor" name="svgColor" value="" />
</form>

$('#changeColor').submit(function() {
    $('#svgColor').val('colorVal');
});
```

Then you can access $_POST['svgColor'] in your PHP script.

Comment: An explanation for the OP. The only things that PHP (or any server side technology) knows about your HTML is the input fields that get submitted with your form. You can set the hidden input fields the from the submit handler if your values are in other places such as element attributes or JavaScript variables

Answer (score 0):

there's no such referring like that to div's in PHP. What you can do to get those values inside your PHP is something like:
    `<div id="my_div_id">my_div_value</div>
    <input type="hidden" name="my_div_id" value="my_div_value">`

Hidden inputs don't show, they're invisible but can keep values.
So you can catch the same value as in the divs, just like this:
    `$div1 = $_POST['my_div_id']; // remember you HAVE to sanitize input, don't assing POST/GET nor any input values without checking the contents!`
Check out [filter_var()](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.sanitization.php) function.

With jQuery you can get/set a select like 
    `<select name="my_select" id="my_select">
    <option value="my_value">text label<option>
    <option value="my_value2">text label<option>
    <option value="my_value3">text label<option>
    </select>`
with
    `$('#my_select').find('option:selected').val(); //get 
    $('#my_select').find('option:nth-child(3)').val('new value!'); //set new option value
    $('#my_select').find('option:nth-child(3)').text('new HTML value!'); //set new text label value`

You can guess the result! And with PHP you can get  option value like this:
    `$selected = $_POST['my_select']; // will take the selected value or empty value if none selected, and again, sanitize!`

Also remeber you always have to give a name to form elements  in order to get them from server side.